# How to retrieve the execution ordering of fetches?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given an array of fetches, how do I retrieve the (possibly non-unique) ordering of fetches that will be executed in a single call to `session.run(fetches)`?

Comment: The order depends entirely on the dependencies in the graph, and could change based upon the way the nodes get placed onto cores.  Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: session.run() computes multiple tensors in one step. I'm trying to implement a debugger that pauses the graph execution after each "fetch" is computed. This can be achieved by calling session.run() on successive fetch ops/tensors and putting results into the feed_dict= paramater. Tricky part is figuring out which fetches to compute first.  I'm trying to make this cost the same as a single call to session.run(). InteractiveSessions don't work because they evaluate all dependencies.

Comment: it's ok if the ordering could change based upon the way the nodes are placed - the behavior will be akin to multi-threaded computation. The only expectation is that if eval on fetch object B depends on eval of fetch object A, then A will be evaluated before B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reasonable solution is to do re-compute the topological sort in python. Looks like the C++ implementation isn't exposed in the python API. Please let me know if there are situations where this wouldn't work.

Here's an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from toposort import toposort


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

matrix1=tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
matrix2=tf.constant([[2.], [2.]])

sum = tf.add(matrix1, matrix2)
product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)
final = tf.mul(sum, product)

g = sess.graph
deps = {}

for op in g.get_operations():
    # op node
    op_inputs = set()
    op_inputs.update([t.name for t in op.inputs])
    deps[op.name] = op_inputs

    # tensor output node
    for t in op.outputs:
        deps[t.name]={op.name}
```

---

```
deps
{u'Add': {u'Const:0', u'Const_1:0'},
 u'Add:0': {u'Add'},
 u'Const': set(),
 u'Const:0': {u'Const'},
 u'Const_1': set(),
 u'Const_1:0': {u'Const_1'},
 u'MatMul': {u'Const:0', u'Const_1:0'},
 u'MatMul:0': {u'MatMul'},
 u'Mul': {u'Add:0', u'MatMul:0'},
 u'Mul:0': {u'Mul'}}

list(toposort(deps))
[{u'Const', u'Const_1'},
 {u'Const:0', u'Const_1:0'},
 {u'Add', u'MatMul'},
 {u'Add:0', u'MatMul:0'},
 {u'Mul'},
 {u'Mul:0'}]
```

Subsequently, we can manually step through evaluation of each node in the graph - subsequent calls to `Session.run()` involve passing in a `feed_dict` that accumulates the results of all previous inputs. This is pretty slow because of the constant shuffling between C++ and numpy data, and memory-intensive because we are caching output values of everything.